# Google Drive API Java client behind proxy

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a java client for Drive API using [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/). However I am getting an error while trying to perform OAuth2 Authentication in my code. I think this might be a proxy issue, which I tried to resolve by setting proxy in my code, but it did not help.

[This](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/java#prerequisites) is the guide which I referred to, for writing my program.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
            // Load client secrets.
            Credential credential = null;

            try{

            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("client_secret.json")));

            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.

            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                      HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                      Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).setDataStoreFactory(
                      DATA_STORE_FACTORY).build();

            credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

            System.out.println(
                    "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(0);
                }
            return credential;

        }

        /**
         * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
         * @return an authorized Drive client service
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","10.3.100.207") ;
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080") ;

            Credential credential = authorize();
            return new Drive.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
        }
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
2016-05-19 18:41:54.989:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2016-05-19 18:41:54.990:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2016-05-19 18:41:55.001:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:51307
Please open the following address in your browser:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=904439877486-uqiqmstss1bdcmhabt0gom905jo3hqsv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:51307/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
2016-05-19 18:42:28.496:INFO::Stopped SocketConnector@localhost:51307
java.net.UnknownHostException: accounts.google.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:79)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:82)
at DriveAPITest.authorize(DriveAPITest.java:84)
at DriveAPITest.getDriveService(DriveAPITest.java:104)
at DriveAPITest.main(DriveAPITest.java:116)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at DriveAPITest.main(DriveAPITest.java:121)
```

I opened the authentication link my browser and after approving the permissions it showed the following message :

> Received verification code. You may now close this window...

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: "Received verification code. You may now close this window." means you are doing the right thing, you are in the right track. Can you please elaborate what is the exact problem? And please include error logs. Your current log seems ok.

Comment: @noogui I have edited my question to include the complete error log. Please check. My program exits after printing this message. Even I can't understand the exact issue.

Comment: Can you try Direct Connection for now as opposed to proxy connection to confirm it is indeed the root cause?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @noogui no, I ended up doing away with the library and directly calling the Rest API using curl, in which I was successful.

Comment: I am also facing same issues, any updates?

Comment: @ammu I did away with the library, and called the Rest API using curl through my code. As per my understanding proxy settings are currently not supported in the library.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your proxy and HttpTransport:

```
final Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("your address", port));
final HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().setProxy(proxy).build();

// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                                        .setAccessType("offline")
                                        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [this article](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup) I simply had access to gsheets behind my corporate proxy just setting https proxy in this way

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myipproxyaddress");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "myipproxyport");

HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
```

and with the remaining code as described in [this example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) 
It doesn't work if I only set http (not https) proxy

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and I have been still struggling with this, so, although the question is quite old, I put here my solutions as well.
So, I managed to go through an authenticated proxy by:

1. Defining a HTTPTransport (I used the ApacheHttpTransport) this way:

```
private HttpTransport buildTransport() {        
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = ApacheHttpTransport.newDefaultHttpClientBuilder();            
        String proxyHost = HOSTNAME;
        int proxyPort = PORT;           
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        clientBuilder.setProxy(proxy);
        String proxyUsername = USERNAME_OR_NULL;
        String proxyPassword = PASSWORD_OR_NULL;
        if (proxyUsername != null && proxyPassword != null) {
            CredentialsProvider proxyCredentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            proxyCredentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort), 
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));         
            clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(proxyCredentialsProvider);
        }
        clientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());
        clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy)); // The magic happens here       
    return new ApacheHttpTransport(clientBuilder.build());
}
```

2. Using it when building the AuthorizationCodeFlow:

```
HttpTransport transport = buildTransport();
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(transport, new GsonFactory(), CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES).build();
```

3. Or when building the Credentials:

```
Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod())
        .addRefreshListener(this)
        .setClientAuthentication(new ClientParametersAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
        .setJsonFactory(new GsonFactory())
        .setTokenServerUrl(TOKEN_URL)
        .setTransport(transport)
        .build()
        .setAccessToken(state.getAccessToken())
        .setExpirationTimeMilliseconds(state.getExpirationMillis())
        .setRefreshToken(state.getRefreshToken());
```

I hope it helps and I hope I will be able to find this post when I will need it in the future... ...because I know I will.

Comment: Ah... all of this because I do not like to set environment variables. It gives me the shivers...